# Unable to install updates: status-code=409

Tags: software-installation, updates

I want to install updates on my ubuntu but it shows me the error:

> Unable to install updates: status-code=409 kind=snap-change-conflict
> message=snap "core" has "auto-refresh" change in progress

My ubuntu is 20.04 and I was going to update ubuntu core snapd runtime environment but I getting this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting this error when running a `snap update`? If so, you generally do not need to do this as snaps will update themselves. This particular message is saying that there are some changes that are due to be applied. Since we (usually) cannot force an update on a snap, this message is shown.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the ubuntu software update page.

Comment: Interesting that you're getting this Snap-specific message. One option you might try is to open the Software & Updates options, click the "Ubuntu Software" tab, and change the "Download From" location from "Server for {country}" to "Main server". If a regional server is having trouble, you can sometimes get a 409 error.

Comment: I changed that but still not working!

Comment: bear in mind I got this message but it still installed the programs, you might be able to ignore the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue on the same version of Ubuntu. You can try to abort the snap process that seems to be hung.

1. On a terminal run:

   ```
   snap changes
   ```
2. Find the process that is causing the issue and note the ID of the process in the `ID` field.
3. Then run:

   ```
   sudo snap abort xx
   ```

   where `xx` is the ID of the process.

Comment: thanks mate saved my time